# Is there a Phoenix equivalent to Rails Console

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir-iex

I'm just learning Phoenix and Elixir and I'm coming from Ruby/Rails where I work in the REPL using `pry` to inspect my database and application state.

I'm trying to figure out how to interact with my database and models in a Phoenix app. I'm aware of `iex`, but I don't know how to use it inspect my app's database from the repl. Do I need to connect to it with ecto each time from the repl? Is there a `rails console` equivalent. I've checked the Phoenix docs, Elixir Dose, and the Ecto repo, but can't find what I'm looking for. Am I missing something?

Edit: Based on the answer below I found [this](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.6.2/docs/ecto-models#section-experiments-with-our-model) section of the ecto docs. Based on this I can do something like `ArticlesApi.Repo.all ArticlesApi.Article`

Comment: You can save some typing by aliasing the module names: `alias ArticlesApi.{Repo, Article}`. Also, keep in mind that you can very conveniently recompile individual modules from your console (`r Article`), or recompile the whole project using `recompile`. This allows you to leave an `iex` session open all the time, keeping aliases active.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can run `iex -S mix` to run `iex` with the dependencies in your current mix project included.. You can read about this at http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/introduction-to-mix.html

From there you can execute Ecto queries:

```
iex> MyApp.Repo.all(MyApp.User)
```

Running `iex -S mix phx.server` will also start the phoenix server.

Comment: It's also worth noting the convenience of an `iex.exs` file in the root of your project to allow you to setup aliases (so you don't have to precede everything with `MyApp.`). An example would be:

`alias MyApp.Repo
alias MyApp.User
alias MyApp.Car`

Comment: Is there a way I can use this in production environment?

Comment: @Chris.Zou Yes, use `bin/my_app remote_console` in your remote shell.

Comment: This is actually `iex -S mix phx.server` since Phoenix 1.3.

Answer (score 29):

For runtime debug, (like `byebug` or `debugger` or `pry` in rails), use

`require IEx` at the top of your model or controller or views file, then type

`IEx.pry` to wherever you need it to halt at runtime and continue debugging.

Type `h` for help inside the console

**Most importantly, after all that, restart your server with:**

`iex -S mix phoenix.server`

More info: [here](https://medium.com/@diamondgfx/debugging-phoenix-with-iex-pry-5417256e1d11#.jixfllb1l)

Answer (score 6):

If you're working in development, use `iex -S mix phx.server`.

If you need into the console of a deployed release, then go to your release directory and run `bin/<name of your app> remote_console` to open up a remote shell to your app's console.

Answer (score 2):

For me I wanted to run pry inside my Elixir tests. For that you need to prefix your `mix test` command with `iex -S`

In full this would be something like

```
iex -S mix test test/meta_api_web/pages/mutation/update/update_model_test.exs:270
```