# Alias all contents of a module/namepsace in IEX

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

Following the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349418/is-there-a-phoenix-equivalent-to-rails-console) regarding how to load iex with the dependencies of the current project I was able to work with phoenix framework dependencies in a pretty productive manner. However, it gets a bit tedious having to provide the namespace of the Phoenix project for every single thing.

Rather than typing `MyApp.Repo.all(MyApp.User)` I was hoping to be able to do `Repo.all(User)`. I can alias each thing individually with `alias MyApp.Repo, as: Repo` but is there any way to do this for everything all at once?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply call `alias MyApp.Repo` instead of `MyApp.Repo, as: Repo` — it will use the last part of the module name.

In Elixir 1.2 you are able to alias multiple submodules to their own names with one call: `alias MyApp.{Repo, User}`

You also have the option of a `.iex.exs` file which you can use to set up your aliases (per [the IEx docs](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html)). I wouldn't recommend it in this case as you run the risk of having a naming collision. Calling `alias` in an iex session is more explicit.

Comment: That looks like it will work great, thanks! I think aliasing the the phoenix models in the iex.exs file on a per project basis will get me exactly what I need without risking too many collisions.